# How to remove specific pull request from the git branch?

Tags: git, pull-request, git-commit

how can I remove a specific PR but keeping local changes and commits in my branch?

these commits and pushes came after the PR that I want to delete.

1. I have development branch, branch 2 that is created from development .
2. I made changes to branch 2 and opened a PR1
3. merged PR1 to development
4. created a new branch from development called branch 3
5. made some changes to branch 3 and pushed changes.

how can I remove PR1(that came from development branch) in branch3?

Comment: Maybe create branch 3 frommthe state of branch 2 (using the commit hash) before PR1 was merged?

Comment: What do you mean with "remove a PR"? A "PR" is not stored in Git history. Do you want to undo the changes introduced by that PR/branch (reverting all commits; or reverting the merge commit)? Do you want your branch 3 to branch off before the PR/branch was merged? What is the use-case you are trying to solve? Do you want the changes of the initial PR/branch to still be in development or do you want to remove them from the development branch? Or do you simply not want them in your new branch, but still have them once your new branch is merged?